# Calculating the distribution of the sum of the squares of the predictors in linear regression

Tags: regression, distributions, linear-model, linear, multivariate-normal-distribution

I'm calculating the distribution of the sum of the squares of the components of the MLE $\hat{\beta}$ in linear regression with normal errors. We are assuming that $\beta = 0$. The distribution of the MLE is therefore $\hat{\beta} \sim N(0, \sigma^2 (X^TX)^{-1})$ where $X$ is the design matrix of the model and $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the normally distributed errors.

I want to show that the distribution of $\frac{||\hat{\beta}||^2}{\sigma^2}$ is $\sum_{i=1}^{n-p}\lambda^{-1}W_i$, where the $W_i$ are $\chi_1^2$ random variables, and the $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $X$ (in this problem we are given that $X$ is full rank and has an eigendecomposition into $X = UDV^T$).

I've already calculated up to $\hat{\beta} \sim N(0, \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}) = N(0, VD^{-2}V^T)$ but I don't know how to proceed to find the distribution of $||\hat{\beta}||^2 / \sigma^2$, could anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

To be accurate, "$X = UDV^T$" is not the "eigendecomposition", but "singular value decomposition (SVD)" of $X$. And with this SVD of $X$, it must be made clear that the size of $D$ is $n \times p$ (assuming $X$ is $n \times p$), and $U$ and $V$ are order $n$ and order $p$ orthogonal matrix respectively.  So the notation "$D^{-2}$" does not make sense (unless you are using the "[Thin SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Thin_SVD)" in which $U$ is $n \times p$ and $D$ is $p \times p$ as opposed to the common "[Full SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Intuitive_interpretations)" as above).  The correct way is expressing $D$ as $D = \begin{bmatrix}\Lambda \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$, where $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_p)$ is an order $p$ diagonal matrix with $\sigma_1 \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_p > 0$ (which are called singular values of $X$.  The relationship between the eigenvalues $\lambda_j$,
$1 \leq j \leq p$ of the matrix $X^TX$ and $\sigma_j$ are given by $\lambda_j = \sigma_j^2$). Therefore, the true distribution of $\hat{\beta}$ is
\begin{align}
\hat{\beta} \sim N_p(0, \sigma^2V\Lambda^{-2}V^T),
\end{align}
which implies that $\sigma^{-1}\hat{\beta} \overset{d}{=} A\xi$, where $\xi \sim N_p(0, I_{(p)})$ and $A$ satisfies $A^2 = V\Lambda^{-2}V^T$.  In addition, since $V$ is an order $p$ orthogonal matrix, $V^T\xi := W \sim N_p(0, I_{(p)})$. It then follows that
\begin{align}
\sigma^{-2}\|\hat{\beta}\|^2 \overset{d}{=} \xi^TA^2\xi = \xi^TV\Lambda^{-2}V^T\xi =  W^T\Lambda^{-2}W = \sum_{j = 1}^p\sigma_j^{-2}W_j^2 = \sum_{j = 1}^p\lambda_j^{-1}W_j^2.
\end{align}

Therefore, the result you presented is incorrect in that:

1. There are $p$ summands, not $n - p$ summands. To see this more clearly, just consider the simplest $X = \begin{bmatrix}I_{(p)} \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$, for which case $\hat{\beta} \sim N_p(0, \sigma^2I_{(p)})$.
2. $\lambda_j$ is the eigenvalue of $X^TX$, not of $X$. In fact, as a rectangular matrix, it is impossible for $X$ to have eigenvalues.

Comment: (+1) But the complaints about notation are distracting. There is a standard formulation of SVD in which "$D^{-2}$" is often used to refer to the $p\times p$ (not $n\times n$) matrix whose *nonzero* diagonal elements are $d_i^{-2},$ where $d_i$ are the nonzero diagonal elements of $D.$  Although that needs clarifying, it could be done a little less critically.  It might also be worth pointing out that you used the full-rank assumption about $X$ when you concluded there are $p$ terms in the sum.

Comment: @whuber I am not really "criticizing/distracting" OP.  IMO, I have to clarify all the dimensions and basic concepts first before answering this question correctly. For the dimensionality of $D$ (either $n \times p$ in my answer or $p \times p$ as you suggested), I believe I follow the widely-accepted SVD formulation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).  I do have seen some author made $D$ to be $p \times p$, but in that case the dimension of $U$ needs to be adapted accordingly.  But I see your point and will edit the wording a bit.

Comment: As for the full-rank assumption, it was clearly mentioned in OP's question.

Comment: Right: my point was only that it could be helpful to point out *how* you used the full-rank assumption in this solution.  My comment about being critical originates from a general sense of negativity in the post, beginning with stating what $X=UDV^\prime$ is *not* and culminating with a summary of what is *incorrect.* The same points can be made in the same (mathematical and statistical) ways from a positive perspective. Just start off by saying what the SVD really is and end by summarizing what the correct result is. IMHO, such a positive approach is less likely to be misread.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the mean μ=0 and variance (let’s call it Σ) of β, then you can compute the expected value and variance at least.

The expected value is tr(Σ).

The variance is 2 tr(Σ ⋅ Σ).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form_(statistics)?wprov=sfti1

This distribution is a Generalized Chi ² distribution
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution?wprov=sfti1

It may be worth considering if you really want the sum of squares ( β’ β ) , or if you’d be just as happy with β’ Σ⁻¹ β.  That is a lot easier.  It follows a standard Chi² distribution I think.